# Javascript h ref not correctly matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspx

In my web app I have various `.jspx` pages, in one of this I want compose it dinamically by `javascript`.

I want to create a table with the `data` element, every data element have an `index`.

I compose a var, named *url*, with the path and the id of element:
`var url = "${downloaHistodyUrl}"+data[index].id;`

My problem is that the **url** is set correctly (I had used the alert for debug it).  But, when I click on:  `<a href>` element I have the "url" world, instead of the value of the variable and my path is: **"/mypath/"+url+** .

**CODE**:

```
$('#modal_history_${doc.id}').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
     $.getJSON('${historyUrl}', function(data) {
        var html='<table class="table table-hover"><tr><th>Versione</th><th>Nome</th><th>PDF</th><th>Motivazione</th></tr>';
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            html = html+"<tr><td>"+data[index].versione+"</td>";
            if(data[index].fileName != null){
                var url = "${downloaHistodyUrl}"+data[index].id;
                alert(url);
                html = html+'<td>'+data[index].fileName+'</td><td><a href='+url+' ><span class="fa fa-download"> Download</span></a></td>';
            }else{
                html = html+"<td></td>";
            }
            if(data[index].motivazione == "" || data[index].motivazione == null){
                html = html+"<td></td>";
            }else{
                html = html+"<td>"+data[index].motivazione+"</td>";
            }
            html = html+'</tr>';
        });
        html = html+'</table>';
        $('#content_modal_history_${doc.id}').append(html);
     })
});
```

I don't understand why.. 
Anyone can help me?

Comment: are you getting url at alert ?

Comment: Yes, in alert the url is correct!

Comment: What URL you are getting in alert?

Comment: in alert I have what i want in href, that is ` /mypath/id`, in href I have `mypath/+url+`

Comment: what do u want in href? please comment the complete URL.

Comment: I want this: `/mypath/id`, the same value of the variabile url see in alert. But I don't have it, I have the word url, instead of the value of the variable

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the double quotes on the href attribute.
You have `<a href=myurl` while it needs to be `<a href="myurl"`

Also, double-check that you really used single quotes when adding `url` to the string and not double quotes. If you did something like this, it would exactly cause the problem you're describing:

```
html = '<a href="+url+">click me</a>'
```

Your code should read like this:

```
html = html+'<td>'+data[index].fileName+'</td><td><a href="'+url+'"><span class="fa fa-download"> Download</span></a></td>';
```

Comment: Also I thought this was the solution, but the url not change and you are redirected to un unexistent page:  `checklist/docs/+url+`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to escape the slash '/' characters in your url variable. Otherwise they will have the effect you are experiencing, that is, they will make the single quotes appear in the final output.

Edit: In case you didn't understand, what I mean is changing/replacing the slashes (/) with double slashes like (//). I also recommend you to use the concat method instead of using the add (+) operator for strings, for a cleaner code.

Comment: No the problem is not this.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had a similar error recently and got confused by the use of both quote characters in your code. However, I tried replicating your issue on codepen but I couldn't do it, it worked just fine, although I think that @krom has already stated the correct way to achieve it in most situations. Could you give us more information about your environment? ie. Browser, jQuery version and such.

Comment: Of course. Browser Chrome, Bootstrap version:3.3.5,  jquery version is: 1.11.3. Now I will try to replace the tag with a button whose OnClick calls a function in which to pass the doc id. It's not what I want but if I do not find an alternative I'll have to do it

Comment: I did this which is obviously not the same since I didn't use any Ajax but I added the Bootstrap and jQuery versions you specified and the same String concatenation you are doing and the append method and it works. https://codepen.io/Jmartnz/pen/aKGbaJ

What is the actual value of url? Have you checked it doesn't have any strange characters?

Comment: In other part of my app, this way work fine.. I don't understand if there is particular conflict or other problem.

Comment: Try using the JavaScript debugger on your Chrome Browser. Also, let us know the actual value of variable url if it's possible.